TigerGraph GraphQL query of relation edges or neighbor vertices in where argument does not work
I am trying to make a graphql query in Tigergraph that filters based on an edge or neighbor vertex, something like the following
query myQuery {
  myGraph {
    Comment(where: {created_To_User: {to: {id: {_eq: 10}}}}) {
      body
      created_To_User {
        to {
          id
        }
      }
    }
   }
}

That shows up the following issue:
{
“data”: null,
“errors”: [
“\nType Check Error in query (TYP-8017): line 5, col 50\nno type can be inferred for v.created_To_User\n”
]
}

Screenshot:


It looks like there might be an issue with how TigerGraph is interpreting the query. The error message indicates that there's a type inference problem with v.created_To_User.
Here's a revised approach to fix the issue:
Check Schema: Ensure that the schema definitions for the Comment vertex and the created_To_User edge are correctly defined.
Refactor Query: Sometimes breaking down the query into simpler parts can help identify where the issue lies. Let's try simplifying the query and building it up step-by-step.
Simplified Query:
First, ensure you can retrieve basic Comment data:
graphql
query myQuery {
  myGraph {
    Comment {
      body
    }
  }
}
Next, verify that you can retrieve the created_To_User edge:

graphql
query myQuery {
  myGraph {
    Comment {
      body
      created_To_User {
        to {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Finally, add the filtering condition:

graphql
query myQuery {
  myGraph {
    Comment(where: { created_To_User: { to: { id: { _eq: 10 }}}}) {
      body
      created_To_User {
        to {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

If the error persists, it might be a deeper issue with the schema or how TigerGraph handles nested filtering. In such a case, double-check the following:

Ensure the created_To_User edge is correctly defined in the
schema.
Ensure the Comment vertex has the necessary relationships
defined.


Thank you for your comment, I already went through the query from the first without filters until the issue happens so unfortunately that trace couldn't reveal the issue, for the schema definition and relationship it is properly created and as that can be proven by the syntax of graphql has not complained about any the query itself semantically
